# Regular expression which accept number between 1 to 100 along with P or F later

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to prepare regex which accepts the numbers between 1 to 100 along with specific letters and special characters in between.

Validation: Allow user to enter or select different ranges: 1 up to 100 and allow P, F ( Uppercase letters only). special character allowed hyphen "-" and comma.

Valid entries:

```
1,5,10, 15-20, P20-35,F36-40
3,5,10, 15-20, F20-35,P36-50
1,5,10, 15-20, F20-35,P36-60
P1-10,F11-12,13,14,20,99,100
```

`1,5,10, 15-20, P20-35,F36-40`  this will be the single value for the input

I have tried `/^0*(?:[1-9][0-9]?|100)$/gim`, but it's not matching my need.

Language:Javascript

Comment: What exactly are the "valid entries"? Is `1,5,10` valid? Or is it just `1` and `5` and `10` without the commas? What about the (apparent) ranges?

Comment: with comma and without comma both are valid 1,2,5 is valid and 1-3,4-5 also valid

Comment: OK, well that was not clear, and your current regular expression clearly makes no attempt to account for the commas, the ranges, or the "P" and "F" prefixes.

Comment: yea,honestly i was not able to make that regex

Comment: Question has all the data points that constitute a valid problem, description, examples and attempt, why close votes then?

Comment: @anubhava The question doesn't specify which 'flavour' of regex is required; that is, there is no language or platform tag. See the wiki excerpt (usage guidelines) for the `regex` tag.

Comment: @SarjeraoGhadage: What is flavor of this regex or the tool/language where you are using this regex?

Comment: @anubhava Using "Javascript" and "VSCode" for this

Comment: Thanks @SarjeraoGhadage. Please always tag your `regex` questions with flavour' of regex as commented by Adrian.

Comment: @anubhava Sure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex for your requirements:

```bash
^[PF]?(?:100|[1-9]\d?)(?:-(?:100|[1-9]\d?))?(?:,\s*[PF]?(?:100|[1-9]\d?)(?:-(?:100|[1-9]\d?))?)*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YxXhR3/2)

Note that `[PF]?(?:100|[1-9]\d?)` will match any 2 digit numbers between `1`  `100` with an optional prefix `P` or `F`.

Comment: it's almost working.but 12,14-12,
P12-15-12   entries are considered valid .dash "-" should be  between two number.P12-15-12 is not valid

Comment: 0 is considering valid input https://regex101.com/r/aL57Wt/3

Comment: It's working now, Thanks for the guidance.5 years back also u  helped on the regix.

Comment: Is it possible to have one more check as the start value should be smaller than the end like F20-25 is valid but F20-18 is invalid?

Comment: Sorry but that arithmetical comparison won't be possible with just regex.

Comment: It shouldn't allow F25-F30 or P25-P30. P or F should only be used once in a range and it Should be in the start of the range like F25-30 not 25-F30 or P25-30 not 25-P30.i have updated some of the invalid entries here: https://regex101.com/r/YxXhR3/1

Comment: In that case `P1-10,F11-F12,13,14,20,99,100` should also be invalid right?

Comment: check my updated answer